# Pandas: TimeGrouper frequency mismatch

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': 'Carl Mark Carl Joe Joe Carl'.split(),
'Quantity': [1,3,5,8,9,3],
'Date' : [
    DT.datetime(2013,9,1,13,0),
    DT.datetime(2013,9,1,13,5),
    DT.datetime(2013,10,1,20,0),
    DT.datetime(2013,10,3,10,0),
    DT.datetime(2013,12,2,12,0),                                      
    DT.datetime(2013,12,2,14,0),
    ]})

df = df.set_index('Date', drop=False)
```

With the following function:

```
def f(frame):
    cum_sum = 0
    if (len(frame) > 0):
        cum_sum = frame.Quantity.sum()
    frame['cum_sum'] = cum_sum
    return frame

x1 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('20M')).apply(f)
```

I get the output

```
                     Buyer                Date  Quantity  cum_sum
Date                                                                  
2013-09-01 13:00:00  Carl 2013-09-01 13:00:00         1       4
2013-09-01 13:05:00  Mark 2013-09-01 13:05:00         3       4    
2013-10-01 20:00:00  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00         5      25
2013-10-03 10:00:00  Joe  2013-10-03 10:00:00         8      25
2013-12-02 12:00:00  Joe  2013-12-02 12:00:00         9      25
2013-12-02 14:00:00  Carl 2013-12-02 14:00:00         3      25
```

How is this possible that the cum_sum of the first two rows is not 25? If I use 'A' as a yearly quantifier in the TimeGrouper function the cum_sum of the first two rows is computed correctly?

Thank you

Andy

Comment: You code sample seems to get missing information/data/code: there is no Branch data in your df for instance. Running the code sample you provide doesn't give the same result as yours. Can you amend it?

Comment: Hi Boud, sorry there have been some copy-paste issues. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `closed='left'` to the time grouper, otherwise it will not included the first bin (and so its in a different group),
and btw...typo in your function: `cum_sum` not `sum_sum`

```
(Pdb) df.groupby(TimeGrouper('20M',closed='left')).apply(f)
                    Buyer                Date  Quantity  cum_sum
Date                                                            
2013-09-01 13:00:00  Carl 2013-09-01 13:00:00         1       29
2013-09-01 13:05:00  Mark 2013-09-01 13:05:00         3       29
2013-10-01 20:00:00  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00         5       29
2013-10-03 10:00:00   Joe 2013-10-03 10:00:00         8       29
2013-12-02 12:00:00   Joe 2013-12-02 12:00:00         9       29
2013-12-02 14:00:00  Carl 2013-12-02 14:00:00         3       29
```